# My delete buttons broke - Error with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This was working perfectly and now I'm not sure what happened.

Here are the errors:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /status_updates/92
Couldn't find User with id=92
```

and

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /status_updates/delete_all
Couldn't find User with id=delete_all
```

What happens is I have users that have many status updates. 92 here should refer to status update 92 that belongs to this user.

I haven't changed any of my code directly relating to this so I suspect it has something to do with a change I tried to make with my coffee-script. (I removed it from my gem file, ran bundle install, and then decided to try to live with out removing it, so I put it back in the gem file, ran bundle install again... and that's it.)

Anyway, the error occurs when I'm in show.html and I'm clicking either of my delete buttons. Either the delete_all or delete for a singular status_update.

Here's the controller methods for all of these which I didn't change at all:

```
def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @status_updates = @user.status_update
end

def destroy
 @status_update.destroy
 flash[:success] = "Status update deleted!"
 redirect_to status_update_path(current_user.id)
end

def delete_all
 @all_status_updates = current_user.status_update
 @all_status_updates.delete_all
 flash[:success] = "All status updates deleted!"
 redirect_to status_update_path(current_user.id)
end
```

In my console I can look up this user and check out it's status updates, and the status updates are all there as I expect them to be. Which is a good thing.

But ActiveRecord can't find them all of a sudden??

Oh yea.. and here is my gem file relating to status_updates for the delete_all button

```
resources :status_updates do 
 collection do 
   delete :delete_all
 end
end
```

The delete buttons look like this:

```
 <%= link_to "delete", status_update, method: :delete %> 
 <%= link_to "Reset Log", delete_all_status_updates_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure? Once this log is reset there is no going back!"}%>
```

I put those there to demonstrate their paths.

This should teach me to write my test and push all my work to git instead of running unsecured :/

Thanks!

Comment: So which line throws this error?

Comment: @user = User.find(params[:id])

Comment: it is looking for a user with id = 92, which you don't have, hence the error. Your delete button should refer to ```destroy``` or ```delete_all``` methods, not ```show```

Comment: Yea I know. Which is why I'm confused. I just updated my question to include the paths the buttons call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that most likely you don't have javascript properly enabled. In Rails the `delete` method is done via javascript. Make sure you include all js files properly in your layout and `application.js`. You need to have either prototype or jquery.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question, but choices are not limited to prototype or jquery, you can also use mootools for instance (and probably others)

Comment: You might be on to something Zepplock because I was messing with my application.js file earlier today.

Comment: These two are in there and I know one is missing. // = require jquery
// = require_tree .

Comment: YES! That was it. I was missing the = require jquery_ujs. 

Thanks!